# How to use sort to sort a vector in a class

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I was wondering how I can use the sort function to sort a vector which is private in a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    const vector<int> myvec;
    A(vector<int>& vec) : myvec(vec) { }

public:
    const vector<int>& getvec() { return myvec; }

    int get_sec_element(){
        int sec_ele = 0;

        sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());

        sec_ele = myvec[2];
        return sec_ele;
    }
};
```

So if I created `A myvec_object` and filled it with a vector which had values already inside it, caliing myvec_object.get_sec_ele() would return the 2nd element in the vector. However, the compiler is giving a huge error message with: "instantiated from here". What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide more information. "instantiated from here" is just a part of a multiline error message.

Comment: `myvec[2]` is the third element, not the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared `myvec` as `const` -- how would you expect to modify it?

Declare `myvec` as:

```
vector<int> myvec;
```

Answer (score 5):

You have defined your vector as `const`; this makes it immutable after initialization. If you intend to sort the vector, you'll need to un-const it, or make a copy to sort (which would be slow, of course, if you intend to do this more than once).

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the member variable `myvec` as `const`, but `std::sort` has to modify the vector to sort it.  You could:

- Make the vector non const by removing the `const` keyword from its declaration
- First make a copy of the vector and sort the copy
- replace `std::vector` with `std::multiset`, which will keep the items in sorted order to begin with.

Comment: `std::multiset<>` doesn't provide random access, so there would be no constant-time mechanism for obtaining elements other than the first or last.

Comment: It's not clear that random access is actually needed for what the original question is asking.  In fact, this seems only to return the kth smallest element, for which no sorting is actually needed

Comment: I tend to agree that the OP probably isn't asking for the right thing. Just thought I'd mention the obvious. ;-]

Comment: Well, it's a fair point and if you do need random access, my third suggestion probably won't do; but the first two are still useable.  You could also sort into a vector at constructor time to get most of the benefits of both.